# How to add a document to a collection in Mongo DB?

Tags: mongodb

I've been looking at Mongo DB and am struggling with getting the basics right.

The following code seems to work on the Mac but doesn't work on Windows. I get no errors on Windows. If I change the username/password to an incorrect combination, I get an error. It doesn't give any output at all when there are no problems with the code but no collection is created in the database at all, whereas I expect there to be one called `things`.

I ran code from the examples in `.\node_modules\mongoose\examples` and it worked fine. I've also tried to place the code in `thing\index.js` within `data.js` just in case making a module was causing an issue but there was no change in behavior. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my sample code:

**data.js**

```
var loremIpsum = require('lorem-ipsum'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Thing = require('./thing');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@localhost/Test', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    createData();
})

function createData() {
    Thing.model.create({
        id: 1,
        name: loremIpsum({
            count: 5,
            units: 'words',
            format: 'plain'
        }),
        description: loremIpsum({
            count: 100,
            units: 'words',
            format: 'plain'
        })
    }, function (err, thing) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        console.log(thing.name);
    });

    mongoose.disconnect();
}
```

**thing/index.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var thingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id: {
        type: Number,
        min: 1
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    }
});
var thingModel = mongoose.model('Thing', thingSchema);

exports.schema = thingSchema;
exports.model = thingModel;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schoolboy error! I'm leaving this here for other noobs to find!

Essentially, my code was disconnecting before the create had a chance to complete. That's why the callback was never being called. *`*facepalm*`*

**data.js**

```
var loremIpsum = require('lorem-ipsum'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Thing = require('./thing');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@localhost/Test', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    createData();
})

function createData() {
    Thing.model.create({
        id: 1,
        name: loremIpsum({
            count: 5,
            units: 'words',
            format: 'plain'
        }),
        description: loremIpsum({
            count: 100,
            units: 'words',
            format: 'plain'
        })
    }, function (err, thing) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        console.log(thing.name);

        // this goes here...
        mongoose.disconnect();
    });

    // this does not go here...
    // mongoose.disconnect();
}
```